# Is there a simple equivalent of :g/PATTERN/m0 that doesn't reverse the matched lines?

Tags: global-command

Occasionally I want to move all lines in a file to the top of that file. `:g/PATTERN/m0` almost does what I want, but because `:g` operates one line at a time in order, it will also reverse the affected lines.

---

Example:

Consider this file. Say I want to separate lines containing a number and move them to the top of the file. `:g/\d/m0` does almost what I want (fr4nk, car0l and b0b are moved to the top) -- but it reverses the order of the matched lines.

```
alice
b0b
car0l
dan
eve
fr4nk
```

Actual output:

```
fr4nk
car0l
b0b
alice
dan
eve
```

Desired output:

```
b0b
car0l
fr4nk
alice
dan
eve
```

---

One way of doing what I want is to use `:g/PATTERN/m$` (which won't reverse lines) and then move the lines from the bottom of the file to the top. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: well, if nothing else works, you can always run the command twice, or type `@:`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of moving the target lines up (and reversing them), move all the non-target lines down.  Since lines are processed top-to-bottom, the order of non-target lines will be preserved.  Also, the target lines will remain in order at the top of the buffer.

```
:v/\d/m$
```

`:v` is the opposite of `:g`, it applies to all lines not matching a pattern.

Comment: That's really awesome, and seems very powerful. Where is the related documentation? `:help v` shows a lot of information, but it doesn't seem to described the above command. All I could find is https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_g

Comment: @EricDuminil  `:help :v` which refers to `:g!` in the previous paragraph, where it is described.

Answer (score 4):

It's not as easy as I would like it to be, but you can do something like this:

```
:let @a='' | exe 'g/\d/d A' | 0put a
```

The breakdown is that it clears register a, executes a delete of all matching lines into register a (uppercase appends to the register instead of replacing it), then puts the contents of register a before the first line of the file.

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd probably just run the `:global` command in command-line mode, and perform the first and third steps with normal mode commands: `qaq`, and `gg"aP`

Answer (score 3):

One more possibility :)

Add an empty line to the top. This will mark that line with the `.` mark. Then use the `:g` command and move all lines below that mark. Since the `:g` is making changes, the '.' mark will be updated to point to the latest moved line (and finally remove that empty line again).

```
0put=[]|g/\d/m '.
1d
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution which is more complex.  On the other hand, it leaves a nice separator between the target lines and the rest of the buffer.

```
:call append(0, '####')|1mark a|g/\d/m'a-1
```

It works like this:

1. add a new line at the top of the buffer.
2. create a mark called `a` on the first line (the newly added one)
3. move matching lines before mark a

One thing to understand about vim marks is that when lines are added above, vim adjusts the mark's position lower.  So address `'a-1` always refers to the line right above the `####` line.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with the `:v` approach mentioned by @Mass. Here is another solution. Move the matching lines to the bottom of the file and afterwards move those lines to the top:

```
exe 'g/\d/m$' | '.,$m0
```

You need to use `exe`here, because the `|` is otherwise seen as argument to the `:g` command. It makes use of the `.` mark for moving those lines of the latest change.